# Avoiding spam in an Ionic Framework / Cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, spam

i'm creating an application using Ionic Framework (Cordova) and it sends POST request to my remote server.

The thing is that i'm sure that some people are going to find a way to flood and spam my server.

I know that the way to avoid this is by identifying the user, and block any request from him... the problem is that I'm not sure how to identify a user based on his cellphone.

I was thinking, maybe by MAC Address, or something like that, I don't want them to need being registered, I'm creating some sort of sim simi.

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: i dont think this is related to ionic or cordova

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely hard to work around due to the nature of the type of communications. This problem also exists in native apps. Anyone with an app installed with permissions to monitor network traffic can see exactly how your POST request is constructed and just copy it.

That being said you can mitigate the problem to some extent. The best way I have found is to have a server side API in the middle, this can then make the proper request to the endpoint and return the result back to your app.

**Example**

APP > MIDDLE_API(stores API credentials/key) > ENDPOINT(received correct key and carrys out request) > MIDDLES_API(receives the data from the endpoint) > APP

This way you can perform any checks on the source of the request in you MIDDLE_API before using the ENDPOINT

If you feel like your API has been compromised you have the control to some degree.